# Как разбить код на модули?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю модули javascript.

Хочу разбить следующий код на модули. Как лучше это сделать?

И если можно, то лучше с частными примерами

```js
var plan = [
  "############################",
  "#      #    #      o      ##",
  "#                          #",
  "#          #####           #",
  "##         #   #    ##     #",
  "###           ##     #     #",
  "#           ###      #     #",
  "#   ####                   #",
  "#   ##       o             #",
  "# o  #         o       ### #",
  "#    #                     #",
  "############################"
];

function Vector(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Vector.prototype.plus = function(other) {

  return new Vector(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
};

//var grid = ["top left",    "top middle",    "top right",
//            "bottom left", "bottom middle", "bottom right"];
//console.log(grid[2 + (1 * 3)]);
// → bottom right

function Grid(width, height) {
  this.space = new Array(width * height);
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}


Grid.prototype.isInside = function(vector) {
  return vector.x >= 0 && vector.x < this.width &&
    vector.y >= 0 && vector.y < this.height;
}
Grid.prototype.get = function(vector) {
  return this.space[vector.x + this.width * vector.y];
};
Grid.prototype.set = function(vector, value) {
  this.space[vector.x + this.width * vector.y] = value;
}

var grid = new Grid(5, 5);
console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1)));
// → undefined
grid.set(new Vector(1, 1), "X");
console.log(grid.get(new Vector(1, 1)));
// → X

var directions = {
  "n": new Vector(0, -1),
  "ne": new Vector(1, -1),
  "e": new Vector(1, 0),
  "se": new Vector(1, 1),
  "s": new Vector(0, 1),
  "sw": new Vector(-1, 1),
  "w": new Vector(-1, 0),
  "nw": new Vector(-1, -1)
};

function randomElement(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

function BouncingCritter() {
  this.direction = randomElement(Object.keys(directions));
};

BouncingCritter.prototype.act = function(view) {
  if (view.look(this.direction) != " ")
    this.direction = view.find(" ") || "s";
  return {
    type: "move",
    direction: this.direction
  };
};

function elementFromChar(legend, ch) {
  if (ch == " ")
    return null;
  var element = new legend[ch]();
  element.originChar = ch;
  return element;
}

function World(map, legend) {
  var grid = new Grid(map[0].length, map.length);
  this.grid = grid;
  this.legend = legend;

  map.forEach(function(line, y) {
    for (var x = 0; x < line.length; x++)
      grid.set(new Vector(x, y),
        elementFromChar(legend, line[x]));
  });
}

function charFromElement(element) {
  if (element == null)
    return " ";
  else
    return element.originChar;
}

World.prototype.toString = function() {
  var output = "";
  for (var y = 0; y < this.grid.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.grid.width; x++) {
      var element = this.grid.get(new Vector(x, y));
      output += charFromElement(element);
    }
    output += "\n";
  }
  return output;
}

function Wall() {}
var world = new World(plan, {
  "#": Wall,
  "o": BouncingCritter
});
console.log(world.toString());
// → ############################
//   #      #    #      o      ##
//   #                          #
//   #          #####           #
//   ##         #   #    ##     #
//   ###           ##     #     #
//   #           ###      #     #
//   #   ####                   #
//   #   ##       o             #
//   # o  #         o       ### #
//   #    #                     #
//   ############################

var self = this;

var test = {
  prop: 10,
  addPropTo: function(array) {
    return array.map(function(elt) {
      return this.prop + elt;
    }.bind(this));
  }
};
console.log(test.addPropTo([5]));
// → [15]


Grid.prototype.forEach = function(f, context) {
  for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
      var value = this.space[x + y * this.width];
      if (value != null)
        f.call(context, value, new Vector(x, y));
    }
  }
};

World.prototype.turn = function() {
  var acted = [];
  this.grid.forEach(function(critter, vector) {
    if (critter.act && acted.indexOf(critter) == -1) {
      acted.push(critter);
      this.letAct(critter, vector);
    }
  }, this);
};

World.prototype.letAct = function(critter, vector) {
  var action = critter.act(new View(this, vector));
  if (action && action.type == "move") {
    var dest = this.checkDestination(action, vector);
    if (dest && this.grid.get(dest) == null) {
      this.grid.set(vector, null);
      this.grid.set(dest, critter);
    }
  }
};

World.prototype.checkDestination = function(action, vector) {
  if (directions.hasOwnProperty(action.direction)) {
    var dest = vector.plus(directions[action.direction]);
    if (this.grid.isInside(dest))
      return dest;
  }
};

function View(world, vector) {
  this.world = world;
  this.vector = vector;
}
View.prototype.look = function(dir) {
  var target = this.vector.plus(directions[dir]);
  if (this.world.grid.isInside(target))
    return charFromElement(this.world.grid.get(target));
  else
    return "#";
};
View.prototype.findAll = function(ch) {
  var found = [];
  for (var dir in directions)
    if (this.look(dir) == ch)
      found.push(dir);
  return found;
};
View.prototype.find = function(ch) {
  var found = this.findAll(ch);
  if (found.length == 0) return null;
  return randomElement(found);
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  world.turn();
  console.log(world.toString());
  //animateWorld(world);
}

var directionNames = Object.keys(directions);

function dirPlus(dir, n) {
  var index = directionNames.indexOf(dir);
  return directionNames[(index + n + 8) % 8];
}

function WallFollower() {
  this.dir = "s";
}

WallFollower.prototype.act = function(view) {
  var start = this.dir;
  if (view.look(dirPlus(this.dir, -3)) != " ")
    start = this.dir = dirPlus(this.dir, -2);
  while (view.look(this.dir) != " ") {
    this.dir = dirPlus(this.dir, 1);
    if (this.dir == start) break;
  }
  return {
    type: "move",
    direction: this.dir
  };
};

function LifelikeWorld(map, legend) {
  World.call(this, map, legend);
}
LifelikeWorld.prototype = Object.create(World.prototype);

var actionTypes = Object.create(null);

LifelikeWorld.prototype.letAct = function(critter, vector) {
  var action = critter.act(new View(this, vector));
  var handled = action &&
    action.type in actionTypes &&
    actionTypes[action.type].call(this, critter,
      vector, action);
  if (!handled) {
    critter.energy -= 0.2;
    if (critter.energy <= 0)
      this.grid.set(vector, null);
  }
};

actionTypes.grow = function(critter) {
  critter.energy += 0.5;
  return true;
};

actionTypes.move = function(critter, vector, action) {
  var dest = this.checkDestination(action, vector);
  if (dest == null ||
    critter.energy <= 1 ||
    this.grid.get(dest) != null)
    return false;
  critter.energy -= 1;
  this.grid.set(vector, null);
  this.grid.set(dest, critter);
  return true;
};
actionTypes.eat = function(critter, vector, action) {
  var dest = this.checkDestination(action, vector);
  var atDest = dest != null && this.grid.get(dest);
  if (!atDest || atDest.energy == null)
    return false;
  critter.energy += atDest.energy;
  this.grid.set(dest, null);
  return true;
};
actionTypes.reproduce = function(critter, vector, action) {
  var baby = elementFromChar(this.legend,
    critter.originChar);
  var dest = this.checkDestination(action, vector);
  if (dest == null ||
    critter.energy <= 2 * baby.energy ||
    this.grid.get(dest) != null)
    return false;
  critter.energy -= 2 * baby.energy;
  this.grid.set(dest, baby);
  return true;
};

function Plant() {
  this.energy = 3 + Math.random() * 4;
}
Plant.prototype.act = function(context) {
  if (this.energy > 15) {
    var space = context.find(" ");
    if (space)
      return {
        type: "reproduce",
        direction: space
      };
  }
  if (this.energy < 20)
    return {
      type: "grow"
    };
};

function PlantEater() {
  this.energy = 20;
}
PlantEater.prototype.act = function(context) {
  var space = context.find(" ");
  if (this.energy > 60 && space)
    return {
      type: "reproduce",
      direction: space
    };
  var plant = context.find("*");
  if (plant)
    return {
      type: "eat",
      direction: plant
    };
  if (space)
    return {
      type: "move",
      direction: space
    };
};
```

Comment: для начала просто разбейте все на `один класс - один модуль`

Comment: Webpack в студию